# How can I insert the result of one query to another database by powershell

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell

My problem is that I need to use powershell script to connect to a database and query some results and immediately connect to another database and insert to another database. My example code is as follows and it seems does not work

```
$rs1 = SQLCMD -W -h-1 -S $server1 -d $database1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select ErrorLogId, CreatedDtim from dbo.ErrorLog where  order by CreatedDTim DESC;"
SQLCMD -W -h-1 -S $server2 -d $database2 -Q "Insert into dbo.ErrorLog $rs1"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit that I have zero experience with PowerShell interop with SQL, so this is mostly just an educated guess, but does it make sense that $rs1 is of some DataTable type that doesn't map as a T-SQL parameter and doesn't print in T-SQL syntax?

If I were doing something like this in C#, as I am wont to do, I'd have to parse out $rs1 and loop through every row. In other words, I'd need something similar to the following pseudo-pseudo-code:

```
var datatable = getTable("select ErrorLogId, CreatedDtim from dbo.ErrorLog where  order by CreatedDTim DESC");
bool first = true;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO dbo.ErrorLog VALUES ");
foreach(var row in datatable.Rows)
{
    if(first)
        first = false;
    else
        builder.append(", ");

    builder.append("(" + row["ErrorLogId"] + ", " + row["CreatedDtim"] + ")");
}

executeNonQuery(builder.ToString());
```

Clearly lots of that is bad practice and it's not super clean, but you get the point. By simply inserting the datatable parameter, you're relying on the ToString of DataTable magically turning it into T-SQL code.

The other option here is if you wanted to do cross-server queries, I believe that's supported by some versions of SQL Server.